# process.kill() does not kill the process

Tags: python, multithreading

I want to start a process from python and wait till exits. Also, if it throws error, I check if the string "error" is printed by it on terminal and if yes, I just want to kill it and proceed. I also want to write all terminal output to file. My current code looks like this:

```
def monitor_process(process, file):
    while True:
        if process.stdout:
            outline = process.stdout.readline().decode()
            file.write(outline)
            file.flush()
            if "error" in outline:
                file.write("stdout: Error encountered. Exiting process.\n")
                file.flush()
                process.kill() // in debug mode, code flow reaches here when process outputs "error" on terminal. However it doesnt kill process.
                break

def runProcess(flight_path):
    output_file = flight_path + "/Process_terminal.log"
    with open(output_file, "w") as file:
        os.chdir("./build")
        command = "./Process"
        process = subprocess.Popen(command, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
        output_thread = threading.Thread(target=monitor_process, args=(process, file))
        output_thread.start()
        process.wait()  
        output_thread.join()
```

As you can read in the comment, when process prints "error" to terminal, the code flow does indeed reaches `process.kill()` line, but executing that lines does not actually kill the process. What I am missing here?

Comment: Is `Process` a shell script? You're probably killing the shell process, but not its child processes.

Comment: Another possibility is that you're killing it, but it sticks around as a zombie until it gets reaped by Python.

Comment: @Barmar given `process = subprocess.Popen(command, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)`, it does appear to be a shell process.

Comment: There's no need to use `shell=True`. You have no shell syntax in `command`.

Comment: Try `terminate()` rather than `kill()`.  SIGKILL is drastic. It doesn't handle subprocesses.